# Create global method to show Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.mdiParent=this;
frm.show();
```

I want to create a global method `showFrm(Form formToShow)` which i can access from anywhere in my project.

I've tried.

```
public void showFrm(Form formToShow)
{
    formToShow f=new formToShow();//getting error here
    f.mdiParent= mdiForm;
    f.show();
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting? Also, methods, not functions

Comment: Of course you're getting an error, you're passing an instance of type, and then trying to create instance from it. That's plain impossible. But why do you need that?

Comment: to write single line again and again instead of 3

Comment: Are you sure you'll always use same (parameterless) constructor, and never set anything but `MdiParent` before calling `Show`?

Comment: error= the type or namespace name 'formToShow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: yes, by midForm i mean the only parent form i hv in my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this method in your "only parent form" class:

```
public void ShowMdiChild<T>() where T: Form, new()
{
    var form = new T();
    form.MdiParent = this;
    form.Show();
}
```

Usage:

```
yourOnlyParentForm.ShowMdiChild<SomeForm>();
```

I would also remind you that C# is case-sensitive.